# angular 4 and rxjs - preventing canceled requests from hitting the server

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a table, where I wish to trigger an http request each time the user hovers above one of the rows. However, I want to send the request only if the user spent at least 200ms above the row. I know that `switchMap` allows you to cancel http requests, but that doesn't prevent an http request which is already on its way from hitting the server, does it? Should I implement some other logic for debounce, for example with `Subject` and `debounceTime`?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that there's anyway to do that but I'd like to be wrong.

Comment: Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dom,'mouseover').timer(200).switchMap(()=>fetch('www..')).subscribe(), but it still won't cancel if http on it's way

Answer (score 0):

As you point out switchMap will kill the previously subscribed observable.

In the comment above Fan Cheung is using fetch. Fetch doesn't support canceling.

Angulars HttpClient does support canceling a http request, so you are in luck.

Depending on how you are getting you hover events you can handle it differently.
But I can show you a version using a subject

(untested code)

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <table>
            <tr
                *ngFor="let item of items"
                // on hover we pass the current item to the mouseOver handler
                (mouseover)="mouseOver(item)"
            >
                <td>{{item}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        // if there is a hovered item we show it
        <div *ngIf="hovered$ | async; let hoverItem">
            {{hoverItem}}
        </div>
    `
})
export class TableComponent extends Component {

    items = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

    // a stream of hovered items
    hoverSubject = new Subject();

    // a stream of requested hover items
    // that have been debounced
    hoverItem$: Observable<string>;

    constructor() {
        this.hoverItem$ = this.hoverSubject.pipe(
            // only let items pass every 200ms
            debounceTime(200),

            // only pass items that are different from the previous ones
            distinctUntilChanged,

            // do the request
            switchMap(item => this.http.get(`https://something`)),
        );
    }

    // emit new hovered items into the hoverSubject
    mouseOver(item: string) {
        this.hoverSubject.emit(item);
    }

}
```